# How do I make sure that images load in the right order on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have the following JavaScript file with a function called `menu` that calls the `draw` function 4 different times to display 4 different images on the screen.

I need to display them in the order they are coded in, but every time I refresh I get something different. I understand that this is most likely because some of the images load faster than others.

I have looked up some other examples of this on the site and the solution seems to be drawing the images only when all of them are loaded first, however I can't get that to work.

Is there another way?

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var audio = new Audio('sounds/sound.ogg');
cvs.addEventListener("click", function(){
        audio.play();
});
var logoSound;

ctx.fillStyle= "#87ceeb";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1330,800);

function draw(src, a, b) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  };
  img.src = src;
}

function menu() {
    draw("images/clouds.png", 0, 300);
    draw("images/background.png", 0, 360);
    draw("images/display.png", 410, 0);
    draw("images/plank.png", 405, 300);
}

menu();
```

**Update**

```
async function draw(src,x,y) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
  };
img.src = src;
}

// main
(async function menu (){
    await draw("images/clouds.png", 0, 300);
    await draw("images/background.png", 0, 360);
    await draw("images/display.png", 410, 0);
    await draw("images/plank.png", 405, 300);
    await draw("images/info.png", 1195, 660);
}());

function cloud2(){
    ctx.drawImage(cloud, speed, 0);

    cvs.requestAnimationFrame(cloud);
}

menu();
```

Comment: Why not something that draws the next image from the `onload` handler?

Comment: Do you mind giving a quick example of how I could do that for multiple images? Thanks.

Comment: *shrug* There are several ways, off the top of my head, an array of objects describing the image, get the first one and save off the rest, in `onload` all the same function with the remaining array elements. If the array is empty, return and do nothing; normal recursive stuff. Not terribly elegant, but meh.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your draw function asynchronous. The setTimeout call is a simulation of your asynchronous on load handler.

```
    async function draw (msg) {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            let randomDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(msg);
            }, randomDelay);
        });
    }

    (async function (){
        console.log(await draw(1));
        console.log(await draw(2));
        console.log(await draw(3));
        console.log(await draw(4));
    }());
```

Which would guarantee the drawing order.

output is:
1
2
3
4

Comment: I updated my answer to wrap the await calls in an async function. await can only be used inside of async functions. I found this tutorial helpful: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: I did another update, still not sure if that is correct. Am I invoking it correctly?

Comment: `draw` isn't returning anything useful for `await` to use; you'd need to resolve a promise in the `onload` event.

Comment: I got off my phone and actually tested this code :-)async function draw (msg) {
   return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    let randomDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
    setTimeout(() => {
     resolve(msg);
    }, randomDelay);
   });
  }

  (async function (){
   console.log(await draw(1));
   console.log(await draw(2));
   console.log(await draw(3));
   console.log(await draw(4));
  }());

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks Dave - I fixed my answer and actually tested it on a proper computer. My downfall the first time was thinking I could peck working code into an iPhone. It turns out I can't. Mea maxima culpa.

Comment: @VorpalSword I hear ya.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing an image on a canvas is a synchronous operation, what is not, is to load these images.

So split your logic in 1.Loading, then 2.Drawing

The loading part will just create as many `<img>` elements as you need to be drawn, operation greatly cleaned up thanks to Promises.

Once that's done, the drawing part will just iterate over the images and draw them:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function loadImages(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(loadImage));
}

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => Object.assign((new Image()), {
    src: url,
    onload: function(e){res(this)},
    onerror: rej
  }));
}

function drawImages(images) {
  images.forEach((img, i) => ctx.drawImage(img, i * 50, 0));
}

async function begin()  {
  // build up our array of urls
  const urls = Array.from({
    length: 10
  }, () => 'https://lorempixel.com/50/50?' + Math.random());
  // load them all
  const images = await loadImages(urls);
  // draw them all
  drawImages(images);
}

begin().catch(console.error)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="50"></canvas>
```

Note that it is the basic operations when external assets are required:

- Load all required assets.
- Then start using them.